# Configuration file of switches format

Tags: switch, network, netconf

Do we need different config files for each category [aaa, bfd, ptp, lldp, vlan etc] for deployment or can there be a single config file that contains all [aaa, bfd, ptp, lldp, vlan etc] and do they need to be in certain order if they are in combined to a single file?

Comment: What product of network devices are we talking?

Comment: Cisco or Arista switches.

Comment: Cisco uses 1 configuration file. Vlans are stored in a database file, vlan.dat.

Comment: So does that mean valns can't be defined and created from the config files? Do the different features need to be in certain order in the config files (AAA, BFD, MLAG, etc) ? Like AAA has to be at the top and certain part has to be the bottom part?

Comment: Yes, vlans can be created from the config file and information is saved regarding that. The order is irrelevant.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Cown. Do you by any chance have published book or created YouTube tutorials? Just a random question.

Comment: Sorry i don't unfortunately.

Comment: Robinhoodjr if you are looking for online tutorials, another user, @Eddie has some cool stuff on his site: http://www.practicalnetworking.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer.

For Cisco products, devices typically use one configuration file. Vlans are stored in a database file called vlan.dat. The configuration saves information regarding Vlans and creates them on boot up. The order in which configuration should be loaded is irrelevant for Cisco products.